# How to hide code duplication(Text and parameters)? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a simple code that I used three times Text with identical parameters but with different Text. How to avoid code duplication? I used SwiftUI and Xcode 13.4

```
Text(status)
    .fontWeight(.bold)
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .padding(.leading, 5)
    .padding(.trailing, 5)
    .background(stats)
    .cornerRadius(3)
```

Comment: Just create a new `View` with an `@Binding` for the `status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [**DRY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) it by converting it to a function:

```
@ViewBuilder func styledText(_ text: LocalizedStringKey) -> some View {
    Text(text)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .padding(.leading, 5)
        .padding(.trailing, 5)
        .background(stats)
        .cornerRadius(3)
}
```

Then use it like:

```
styledText(status)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `ViewModifier` for your `Text`.

```
struct CustomTextStyle: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding(.leading, 5)
            .padding(.trailing, 5)
            .background(.black)
            .cornerRadius(3)
    }
}
```

You can create an extension of `View` like this to use the above `ViewModifier`.

```
extension View {
    func customTextStyle() -> some View {
        modifier(CustomTextStyle())
    }
}
```

Now set this `ViewModifier` to your `Text`.

```
Text("Hello World")
    .customTextStyle()
```